# Lollipop: OpenVPN connects, no data. Jellybean: Connects, gets data

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, openvpn

I have 2 Azpen tablets, one running 5.1.1, the other running 4.2.2.  I have an OpenVPN server and I am able to connect and use it successfully with a variety of devices (Windows, Linux, and the 4.2.2 tablet).

On both tablets I use OpenVPN Connect.

However, with the 5.1.1 tablet, it connects, I receive 4.02 Mbytes of data, and then nothing else ever happens.  Applications are unable to get any data from the network.

Something else is clearly wrong too, because when I hit Disconnect in OpenVPN Connect, it does not disconnect cleanly. It seems to hang for a few seconds, then I get a message about "threads", and the normal network connection does not come back until I power the tablet off and back on.  If I try to connect again with OpenVPN before the power cycle, it hangs at the DNS step.

The OpenVPN config files on both devices are identical except for the device-specific items.  I have to think there is a setting somewhere on the Lollipop tablet that I'm missing. (I'm much more familiar with the 4.2.2 tablet).

Comparing the logfiles does not shed any light.  I keep coming back to a problem or setting on the tablet that I can't find.

Has anyone else had this problem and fixed it?

Note: apparently not a duplicate of [Can't connect to OpenVPN properly on Lollipop](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/93950/cant-connect-to-openvpn-properly-on-lollipop)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out Lollipop has bugs relating to routing of VPN connections when OpenVPN is used.  This reddit [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/VPN/comments/2rgp2h/openvpn_troubles_on_android_lollipop/) gave me the clue that the problem was routing on the client side.  After a lot of trial and error, by switching to OpenVPN for Android client (which gives better control over settings) I was able to set up manual routes and get it to connect and work.